# test for deviation from uniform distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, uniform-distribution

Imagine I have a 3x3 matrix of the type:

```
[0.22 0.15 0.99

 0.28 0.42 0.51

 0.16 0.76 0.12]
```

The numers in the matrix are the result of a complex model, please simply take them as given.

I would like to test the hypothesis that the matrix values are not "uniformly distributed" over the matrix. By uniformly "distributed" over the matrix I mean we would have a matrix of dimension N where each entry is 1/N, for example

```
[0.11 0.11 0.11

 0.11 0.11 0.11

 0.11 0.11 0.11]
```

Of course, the first matrix is not "uniform". My question is: is there a statistical test to carry out to formally test the hypothesis that each matrix entry does not deviate significantly from 1/N? The ideal statistical test would give me, for example, a low p-value for an entry of, let's say, 0.99, loosely speaking indicating low probability that the null hypothesis is true as 0.99 is very far from 0.11 among all possible realizations in [0,1].

I apologize in advance if I am not too rigorous, but I cannot express this concept better than this. Any kind of hint is very appreciated.

Comment: One thing that's confusing me: your null hypothesis is that the values in the matrix are equal *and sum to 1*. Is there any constraint on the values at all?

Comment: For example, what would you conclude if all the values in the matrix were equal, but not 1/N?

Comment: The part that is most unclear to me is whether or not the matrix structure is necessary.  ¿Is this just a set of 9 values? or ¿is there some concrete interpretation for the matrix?

Comment: What you need is a probabilistic *model* for how the values would be generated under the null hypothesis, not just their expected values, otherwise there's no basis to work out what you might reasonably see when the null is true. You may need to describe the circumstances in more detail.

Comment: @DoctorMilt It would not be a problem, as I could always argue that the are still all equal to 1/N after factoring out a constant

Comment: @GreggH the structure of the matrix is actually not strictly necessary. It is just the way my starting point is, but I guess everthing would work the same if the 9 values were a simple 9x1 vector

Comment: Please explain how the proportions are calculated...¿are they relative frequencies?

Comment: @GreggH they result from a complex model, and we do not know what id the data generating process. I would simply like to test whether the realizations of that process (i.e. what contained in the matrix) come from something similar to a uniform distribution or not